# JEST : unable to access the function in the props

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write the test case for the component where on `componentDidMount()` I am calling two function of my actions that are bind with `bindActionCreators`. I am facing a strange issue that when I render the component with shallow/mount rendering I am getting the error on line :

```
this.props.actions.getsomething()

Error : getSomething of Undefined
```

Component's mounting.

```
componentDidmount () {
  this.props.actions.getSomething();
}
```

My test case for this is :

```
it('it should dispatch action', () => {
        const actionsMock = { getSomething: jest.fn() };
        const localWrapper = shallow(<Componentes actions={ actionsMock } />);
        const instance = localWrapper.instance();
        instance.componentDidMount();
        expect(actionsMock.getSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

here when I put some console.logs in the `componentDidMount()` I am bale to see the `this.props.actions` coming as :

```
{ getSomething:
         { [Function: mockConstructor]
           _isMockFunction: true,
           getMockImplementation: [Function],
           mock: [Getter/Setter],
           mockClear: [Function],
           mockReset: [Function],
           mockRestore: [Function],
           mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
           mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function],
           mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function],
           mockReturnValue: [Function],
           mockResolvedValue: [Function],
           mockRejectedValue: [Function],
           mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
           mockImplementation: [Function],
           mockReturnThis: [Function],
           mockName: [Function],
           getMockName: [Function] },
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: is it occasional `getSomething` has lower case in error message(`getsomething`)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me:

`index.jsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.getSomething();
  }
  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

`index.spec.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import SomeComponent from '.';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  it('it should dispatch action', () => {
    const actionsMock = { getSomething: jest.fn() };
    const localWrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent actions={actionsMock} />);
    const instance = localWrapper.instance();
    instance.componentDidMount();
    expect(actionsMock.getSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57322103/index.spec.jsx (12.116s)
  SomeComponent
    ✓ it should dispatch action (11ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.894s
```